# Slow loading of UITableView. How know why?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, performance

I have a UITableView that show a long list of data. Use sections and follow the sugestion of [How to solve slow scrolling in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695814/how-solve-slow-scrolling-in-uitableview) .

The flow is load a main UITableView & push a second selecting a row from there.

However, with 3000 items take 11 seconds to show. I suspect first from the load of the records from sqlite (I preload the first 200). So I cut it to only 50.

However, no matter if I preload only 1 or 500, the time is the same.

The view is made from IB and all is opaque.

I run out of ideas in how detect the problem. I run the Instruments tool but not know what to look.

Also, when the user select a cell from the previous UITable, no visual feedback is show (ie: the cell not turn selected) for a while so he thinks he not select it and try several times. Is related to this problem.

What to do?

NOTE: The problem is only in the actual device:

- iPod Touch 2d generation
- Using fmdb as sqlite api
- Doing the caching in viewDidLoad
- Using NSDictionary for the caching
- Using a NSAutoreleasePool for the caching part.
- Only caching the row ID & mac 4 fields necesary to show the cell data
- UIView made with interface builder, SDK 2.2.1
- Instruments say I use 2.5 MB in the device

Comment: I take a second look in Instruments and the most expesive call is fmresultset next  (from fdbm library)

Comment: Have you analysed how long it takes to perform the SQL query that fetches the data?

Comment: No idea how. I use SQL SERVER before and know about using tools for this but not for sqlite

Answer (score 2):

The -[FMResultSet next] call can be a very expensive call to make, depending on the data that's getting loaded.  It'd during this call that sqlite is actually going to the database, finding the next row to return, and giving you back the appropriate fields.  It's not just an enumerator.

You might want to consider pre-caching all of the data before actually displaying the table.  This means that you would do all of your FMDB calls before the table gets shown on the screen.

If that takes too long, you might want to show the tableview with its initial rows, and then use NSOperations or just a second thread to load the data in the background and cache it that way.

Comment: Ok, I already cache the first 200 records, but I need to load all the ID so no matter much.

How do this in the background?

Comment: have a method in your tableViewController that loads everything into your cache, then call [NSThread detachThreadSelector:@selector(myCachingMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Plus, don't forget to actually *use* the cache when displaying your cells...

Comment: Ok, but unfortunally I start to have threading issues :( I don't know how use sqlite with both treads using it. Maybe anoter SO question ...

Comment: I now know for sure the problem is in sqlite. I load another complex query and take 1 min to show the table.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, I think I would be inclined to think that you need to index you tables.

You should see an enormous speed up by adding an index on the attributes you query on. You can do this by using the `CREATE INDEX` SQL command.