# Will pool the connection help threading in sqlite (and how)?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.0

I currently use a singleton to acces my database (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084502/how-use-sqlite-fdbm-library-with-threading-on-the-iphone)) but now when try to add some background processing everything fall apart. I read the sqlite docs and found that sqlite could work thread-safe, but each thread must have their own db connection. I try using [egodatabase](http://github.com/enormego/egodatabase) that promise a sqlite wrapper with thread safety but is very buggy, so I return to my old FMDB library I start to see how use it in multi-thread way.

Because I have all code with the idea of singleton, change everything will be expensive (and a lot of open/close connections could become slow), so I wonder if, as the sqlite docs hint, build a pooling for each connection will help. If is the case, how make it? How to know which connection to get from the pool (because 2 threads can't share the connection)?

I wonder if somebody already use sqlite in multi-threading with NSOperation or similar stuff, my searching only return "yeah, its possible" but let the details to my imagination...

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using thread-local variables to hold the connection; if the variable is empty (i.e., holding something like a `NULL`) you know you can safely open a connection at that point to serve the thread and store the connection back in the variable. Don't know how to do this with Obj-C though.

Also be aware that SQLite is *not* tuned for concurrent writes. Writer locks are expensive, so keep any time in a writing transaction (i.e., one that includes an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) to a minimum in all threads. Transaction commits are also expensive too.